# Jmeter: Issue with Constant Timer

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Trying to simulate the follows:

1. 10 users login [For each user auth token extracted and put in header manager].
2. Do whatever action(s) [In the attached pic, this is dormant in the if controller].
3. Logout each user [auth token required].

This works perfectly, until I add a constant timer between steps 1 & 3. It works as long as the timer is < 10 ms. When time is larger the auth token is duplicated [proportional to the timer] and logout fails for remaining users.

The image is updated to include a cookie manager. [Observe the auth token header, this is the same for all requests when the timer is > 30 ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVP2L.jpg)

Comment: Can you show more infos about "When time is larger the auth token is duplicated [proportional to the timer]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a silly mistake actually. I am extracting the auth token from the response body and saving it in a variable and then as a property which is then passed as a Jmeter Request Header for Authentication.

When there is no delay. Jmeter has enough time to complete the entire login -> logout sequence before it initializes and starts the next thread. Hence there are no issues in this case. When we add a timer it is unable to complete the entire process and the new thread overwrites the new Property. Hence the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have put a Cookie Manager in your test plan.
Are you sure that you're not opening a new session for every request ?

I don't think Constant Timer has anything to do with your issue.

Comment: 1. Thank you for your reply. Updated in my original question above is the screenshot of the Test Plan with a cookie manager.
2. No, a new session is not created foe each request.
3. Please note in the screen shot newly attached the auth token every request in the logout controller has the same auth token header. This happens when the timer has a big enough value say > 30 ms.

Any feedback is highly appreciated.